# Highlight selected menu item

Tags: html, css, menu, highlighting

I have this menu:

```
<ul class="semiopaquemenu">
  <li><a href="http://www.artoparadosikilkis.gr/home/">home</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://www.artoparadosikilkis.gr/proionta/">products</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://www.artoparadosikilkis.gr/paraggeleies/">orders</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://www.artoparadosikilkis.gr/location/"class="selected">location</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://www.artoparadosikilkis.gr/about-us/">about-us</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://www.artoparadosikilkis.gr/contact-us/">contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

This is a horizontal menu that is highlighted on mouse over and the current page is highlighted also on click
my question is how can I modify my code so I can put it only one time.
the example highlights the location tab and the code is on the location page 
what I want is something like

```
<ul class="semiopaquemenu">
  <li><a href="http://www.artoparadosikilkis.gr/home/"if selected=true then class="selected">home</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://www.artoparadosikilkis.gr/proionta/"if selected=true then class="selected">products</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://www.artoparadosikilkis.gr/paraggeleies/"if selected=true then class="selected">orders</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://www.artoparadosikilkis.gr/location/"if selected=true then class="selected">location</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://www.artoparadosikilkis.gr/about-us/"if selected=true then class="selected">about-us</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://www.artoparadosikilkis.gr/contact-us/"if selected=true then class="selected">contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: That depends on your CMS or server technologie. Which software are you using?

Comment: i found this function but i can't do it to work with my code
`$(function() {
    $('#navigation li').click(function() {
            $('#navigation li').removeClass('selected');
            $(this).addClass('selected');
            //$('a', this).addClass('selected');
        
    });
});`

Comment: The above code should be written as $(document).ready(function() { $('#navigation li').click(function() { $('#navigation li').removeClass('selected'); $(this).addClass('selected'); }); }); - see http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: To work specifically with the example HTML you have given you would however need to change your selectors as follows- $(document).ready(function() { $('.semiopaquemenu li a').click(function() { $('.semiopaquemenu li a').removeClass('selected'); $(this).addClass('selected'); }); });